# Convert API response to array

Tags: javascript

I have a list of 1000 objects returned from an API; they are structured like

```
{
  val1: {col: 'hjkh', …}, 
  val2: {col: 'hekj', …},
  val3: {col: 'jhkd', …},
  val4: {col: 'kjdj', …},
  val5: {col: 'kjdj', …},
}
```

I would like to convert them using Javascript to something I can iterate as a map in React, something like this would be ideal;

```
const objects = [
  { name: 'val1', col: 'hjkh', …},
  { name: 'val2', col: 'hekj', …}
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
const data = {
  val1: {col: 'hjkh'}, 
  val2: {col: 'hekj'},
  val3: {col: 'jhkd'},
  val4: {col: 'kjdj'},
  val5: {col: 'kjdj'},
};
const result = Object.entries(data).map(([name, values]) => ({name, ...values}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
const data = {
  val1: {col: 'hjkh', …}, 
  val2: {col: 'hekj', …},
  val3: {col: 'jhkd', …},
  val4: {col: 'kjdj', …},
  val5: {col: 'kjdj', …},
};

const res = [];

Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
  res.push({
     name: key, 
     ...data[key]
  });
});
```

I hope this gives a rough idea.

Answer (score -1):

Use [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to do just a single iteration.

```js
let data = await api.get(); //your api call
let arr = [];
for (let prop in data) {
   arr.push({ name: prop, ...data[prop] });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "a single iteration"?

Comment: Here's the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#polyfill) for `Object.keys`. You can see that it is looping. And then using `Array.forEach` or `Array.map` or a different solution with multiple loops is doing more than 1 iteration. That's what i mean, @CharlesBamford

Comment: The polyfill does not necessarily represent the engine implementation of a method. It's just a backwards compatibility layer, and given that this feature has existed in the spec since 2012, it would probably be better to just use the built in.